# Override method within JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to write coupling based test to observate several paths.
I am trying to do it like usual testing using `Assert.*` (I don't know any better way) but for that purpose I need to change the testing methods.

Consider following examples

```
Class A {
public Collection<Object[]> mth1(String a);
do whatever
do whatever
B.mth2(a)
do whatever
return null

Class B
public void mth2 (String a)
a.parse();
do whatever
return null
```

For my testing I'm not interested in actual values, I just need to know if my test comes to a certain point.

Thus, I want to override `mth2` in such way - return is called at line 11 
and `mth1` to call return at line 6 with value 1.

Is there a way to do such thing or better way to test coupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mock library (google search for mock).  create a mock object for class B.  use it in your test.